# How change to keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the ready event into a keyup event.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#coke').validate({
      rules : {
      coek : {
         required: true,
         minlength: 6,
         maxlength: 6
         }
      },
      messages: {},
      errorElement : 'div',
      errorLabelContainer: '.errorTxt'
   });
});
```

Comment: But why? Where do you want to attach the keyup event? On the whole page?

Comment: @MarioMurrent when I type a keyword in search form

Comment: So you should bind the keyup event to your search form not the document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like, assuming you want to attach the keyup event to you input not the whole document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#coke").bind('keyup', function(e) {
        // your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried but still.

when I finish typing does not automatically appear notification, but when I point the cursor to another area will appear

Comment: thank you for saving my day :)

Comment: So you got it to work? :) Thats fine